# how to select all on laravel query builder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

(1)

```
DB::query()
->select(*)    <----how to write it's error
->addSelect(DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN B.approve IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as Ashowcount'))
->addSelect(DB::raw('SUM(B.approve) as Yshow'))
->from(a16 as A)
.....
```

(2)

```
DB::table(a16 as A')
->Select(DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN B.approve IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as Ashowcount'))
->addSelect(DB::raw('SUM(B.approve) as Yshow'))
    ......    <---just select two column
```

I want to ask how can I select all from a16 with above two query code?
I need use addselect to add the DB:raw code

I only can type one by one just like

```
 ->select('A.id','A.s_main','A.s_brand','A.s_model','A.s_price','A.s_count','A.s_unit','A.s_location','A.s_geography','A.s_location','A.u_id','A.classify','A.s_boss','A.route','A.created_at')
```

I feel  it's some no efficiency.

How can I select all column easily?

Comment: Did you actually use `->select(*)`? Or `->select('*')`?

Comment: thanks! Sorry for my neglect！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DB::query()
->select('A.*')    
->addSelect(DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN B.approve IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as Ashowcount'))
->addSelect(DB::raw('SUM(B.approve) as Yshow'))
->from(a16 as A)
```